# not initialized at super.init call

Tags: ios

New to iOS.

How should I resolve this:

```
@objc protocol NwNamew {
    init(vm: ViewModel)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, NwNamew {
    var viewModel: ViewModel

    required init(vm: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = vm
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

getting error: Property 'self.viewModel' not initialized at super.init call

Comment: Dependency injection via custom initialisers doesn't really work as an approach with `UIViewController` subclasses as you cannot add the additional parameter to the inherited initialisers.  You will either need to assign a default `ViewModel` instance in the `init(coder:)` initialiser or make it an optional or implicitly unwrapped unwrapped optional. Read the chapter in the Swift book on initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `super.init(coder:)` you have to have initialised all the variables in the class. As you aren't implementing the `init(coder:)` function in your class you can remove this `super.init(coder:)` call. This will get rid of your compile error.

Answer (score 0):

You could also resolve this error by making the parameter as Optional, as so

```
var viewModel: ViewModel?
```

Optionals are parameters that can be nil and need to be unwrapped before usage.
You could read more here about Optionals:

[Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional)